# $window object is not available in other modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created two separate modules for an AngularJS app. In the first module as soon as I log in, I'm storing the login info and API key in the `$window` object.

```
$window.sessionStorage["apiKey"] = apiKey;
$window.sessionStorage["profile"] = profile;
```

However, I'm not able to access the window object in the second module.

My Question:
Can I use any factory service to access window object from other module?
Or, how can I retain the property in `$window` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a *service* for this purpose

Creation

```
var myService = function ($http) { // injecting $http just for the sake of it
    var service = {};
    service.name = "My Service";

    return service;
};
```

Add to *Module*

```
app.service('myService', ['$http', myService]);
```

Inject into *Controller*

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.serviceName = myService.name;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai-Andrei.But I'm having $window in a different module.Can I use this in other modules?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my answer. You can use that approach to add it to multiple  modules.

Comment: actually, you should probably use constants for this.